Maximum current drawn by Schmitt-Trigger
I'm looking at the SN74LVC1G1 Schmitt-Trigger Buffer.
I want to understand what is the maximum current the chip can draw from the power supply source.
Under "6.5 Electrical Characteristics - DC Limit Changes" I see ICC is 10 µA as maximum current.
But there is another part to consider: the ΔICC. I think this is the deviation from the input current consumption when the output is connected.
Hence, the actual maximum current, under some particular conditions, can be ICC + ΔICC = 510 µA.
There isn't a description about this part. Can you confirm if I understand correctly this?

Static power with the input at either rail:
\$I_{cc} = 10 \mu A\$
If the input is not at the rail (Vcc - 0.6 V is worst case), add:
\$\Delta I_{cc} = 500 \mu A\$
If the input is oscillating, you need to consider the effective internal capacitance, Cpd (26 pF at 5V):
\$\Delta I_{pd} = C_{pd}V_{cc} f \$
\$\Delta P_{pd} = C_{pd}V_{cc}^2 f \$
Any load being driven is separate and must be added.

I think the expression for switching current is CVF not V squared.

@sai It's correct; see How do I Calculate Power Consumption or Current Consumption for my CMOS Logic Device?

Vcc − 0.6 V is not the worst case; that would happen near Vcc / 2. See https://e2e.ti.com/cfs-file/__key/communityserver-discussions-components-files/151/LVC-ICC-vs-VI.png .

@CL. - For a standard CMOS input, yes, worst case is Vcc/2. For a schmitt-trigger input, maybe not.

@Mattman944, do you plan to update the expression for the switching current?

@sai - FIxed equation. For power it is V^2,

@Mattman944 Thank you for this explanation, I think it is now clear the concept.

The maximum supply current (Icc) of 10 µA when the input is at Vcc or GND

For more details please see this document.

Your link is very useful, thank your for sharing!
